# Destroying user in rails gives error with dependant models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to delete a user in my rails application by calling @user.destroy in the userscontroller but it shows me an error with the dependent models.

I'm using devise and I don't know if there is another method for destroying a user in there. I've tried changing to delete_all but didn't work then removing "dependant: :destroy" on the user model in every "has_many" line and adding manually in the controller the code for deleting those objects that depend on that user but it shows me the same error.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  extend Devise::Models

  require 'uri'

  has_one_attached :profile_pic

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :blockeds, class_name: 'block', foreign_key: 'blocked_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :owner_blocks, class_name: 'block', foreign_key: 'owner_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, class_name: 'follow_user', foreign_key: 'followed_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :following, class_name: 'follow_user', foreign_key: 'follower_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :taggeds, class_name: 'tag', foreign_key: 'tagged_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :taggers, class_name: 'tag', foreign_key: 'tagger_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :achievements, through: :achievement_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :downvote_comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :upvote_comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :upvote_posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :downvote_posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :follow_posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :mark_innapropiateds, dependent: :destroy
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
```

users_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Migration for comment

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :post, foreign_key: true
      t.string :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb (Where I call the destroy method for the user)

```
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= user.nickname %></td>
            <td><%= user.email %></td>
            <td><%= user.role %></td>
            <td><%= user.last_sign_in_at %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', user, class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
            <td>
              <% if user.role=='user' %>
                        <%= form_with(model: user, local: true, action: 'make_admin') do |form| %>
                          <%= form.hidden_field :role, value: 'admin' %>
                          <%= form.submit "Make Admin", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                        <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-primary"%></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
```

I expected the user to be deleted with all their dependent objects (in this case their comments). It is only showing me an error with the comments but my guess is that it would show me the same error for the other models. This is the error:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ?
```

## DELETE /users/1.json

```
  def destroy
    @user.destroy (<-- here is remarked)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
```

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"tLUFwuWcM27OKSgrJLoxHTznr82DIFCPFF+InWYnNRpGRyqI5ZIrbUIIP0oaWCB8mVR5mIBI1SPS5E1cynOEmw==", "id"=>"1"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve found the solution. I was missing the foreign cascade in the migrations. I only wrote dependent destroy on the user.rb but forgot about the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Your `upvote_comments` and `downvote_comments` are still dependent on the `comment` therefore you cannot delete the comment if anything references to it.

You need to add `dependent: :destroy` to `upvote_comments` and `downvote_comments` in your comments model.

Comment: I forgot about those, i don't need them anymore so i deleted those 2 lines entirely and it keeps showing me that error.
 Im gonna update comment.rb in the question.